Curve construction and convexity adjustment
I am trying to understand better how to build the front end of the curve.
For SOFR to construct the front end of the curve we can use all the 1 Month SOFR Futures and the 3 Month SOFR futures. Also $\theta_i$ are rate jumps at the FOMC meetings.
Then the idea is to write the 1 &3 month sofr futures as a function of forward rates and $\theta_i$. Hence we have different nodes to solve for which are the FOMC dates and the beginning and end of the futures. So for  example for the December $1$ month future we'll have a node  on the $1$s of December and on the $31$ of December.
Then we solve an optimization problem using the futures as market-prices which will find the jumps on the FOMC dates and the forward curve. Now I have seen people adding regularization on the FOMC jumps, for example adding some penalty term like: $\sum (2\theta_j - \theta_{j-1} - \theta_{j+1})^2$.
Now I have a few questions:

How is the convexity adjustment taken into account in the optimization problem? I didn't find any literature on this
What's the best way to interpolate between the nodes? Should cubic spline be used? and why? I've seen people using cubic spline with knots equal to the IMM dates.
Why does something like: $\sum (2\theta_j - \theta_{j-1} - \theta_{j+1})^2$ make any sense? Because this forces rates cut to be increasing or decreasing, but when there is a change of policy (going from cutting rates to hiking rates) this might create a wrong curve.



Convexity is not usually taken into account in the optimization, its is usually precomputed and added into the prices before the optimization. 2) No, central bank periods have constant rates, the best interpolation to use is log-linear between central bank effective dates. 3) I dont think that does make sense if theta is the difference (ie jumps) between two periods. That equation gives rise to an approximation of setting third derivative of the curve to zero. I think practically most people target the second derivative being zero, which would be $(\theta_j - \theta_{j-1})^2$


@Attack68 interesting, thank you! How would you go about computing the convexity adj? Do you use a close form formula using HW? (but then how do you get the vol and corr). I feel like some people optimize using irs as market prices and add a condition like forward + convexity = future price in the optimizer. So convexity is also a parameter that is free to vary. 3) Ok so for the short end < 2Y people log linear and then for >2Y cubic spline?

Can also have a look here if you like: https://rateslib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/z_convexityrisk.html
